# How to set unique column ID based on other colums via dictionary to every single row in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a Dataframe with about 30,000+ rows and 9 unique columns. I want to generate a unique ID for each of the rows and put it inside a new column. For example :

```
old_car_brand continent country     income_level occupation    new_car_brand
Tesla         Asia      Indonesia   Medium       Businessman   Subaru
Ferrari       Asia      Brunei      Medium       Businessman   Tesla
```

From the above dataframe, I want to create another column with an ID generated based on the other column. I already have an dictionary like below :

```
ID_Dict = {'Tesla' : 'T001',
           'Ferrari' : 'F001',
           'Asia' : 'XASIAX',
           'Brunei' : 'BRUN',
           'Indonesia' : 'INDN'
          }
```

I tried using df.itertuples() to iterate each row and retrieve the information needed, but whenever I wrote the value into the column, the value somehow is set the same for every single row. Below is the sample that I wrote.

```
for row in Test_DF.itertuples():
   a = ID_Dict[row.oldCar]
   b = ID_Dict[row.Continent]
   c = ID_Dict[row.Country]
   d = ID_Dict[row.newCar]
   Test_DF['sales_id'] = a+b+c+d
```

The sales_id column is there but it sets the last row sales_ID to every single row, like below:

```
old_car_brand continent country     income_level occupation    new_car_brand  sales_id
Tesla         Asia      Indonesia   Medium       Businessman   Ferrari        F001XASIAXBRUNT001
Ferrari       Asia      Brunei      Medium       Businessman   Tesla          F001XASIAXBRUNT001
```

But I want the result to be like below (based on the dictionary):

```
old_car_brand continent country     income_level occupation    new_car_brand  sales_id
Tesla         Asia      Indonesia   Medium       Businessman   Ferrari        T001XASIAXINDNF001
Ferrari       Asia      Brunei      Medium       Businessman   Tesla          F001XASIAXBRUNT001
```

What did I do wrong? Is there a way for me to go to every row, generate the id based on their column's value, link the value to the dictionary, and put the ID inside a column? Thank you in advance~

Comment: subaru is not listed in the `ID_Dict` dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one-liner would do the job:

```
df['sales_id'] = df.apply(lambda row: ID_Dict[row['old_car_brand']] + ID_Dict[row['continent']] + ID_Dict[row['country']] + ID_Dict[row['new_car_brand']], axis = 1)
```

Loops are always time-consuming.

You have used different column names in the dataframe and the loop. I believe that is a typo. Here I have assumed the column names to be the ones in the example dataframe you have provided. Also I have assumed the entry 'Subaru' to also be present in the dictionary with value 'S001'.

Change `df` to the name of your dataframe.

Sample Output:

```
+----+-----------------+-------------+-----------+----------------+--------------+-----------------+--------------------+
|    | old_car_brand   | continent   | country   | income_level   | occupation   | new_car_brand   | sales_id           |
|----+-----------------+-------------+-----------+----------------+--------------+-----------------+--------------------|
|  0 | Tesla           | Asia        | Indonesia | Medium         | Businessman  | Subaru          | T001XASIAXINDNS001 |
|  1 | Ferrari         | Asia        | Brunei    | Medium         | Businessman  | Tesla           | F001XASIAXBRUNT001 |
+----+-----------------+-------------+-----------+----------------+--------------+-----------------+--------------------+
```